# A 5 member committee is to be chosen from 15 students and 10 teachers

Tags: probability

> A $5$ member committee is to be chosen from $15$ students and $10$ teachers.
>   a) Determine the probability the committee will have at least one student AND at least two teachers.

So what I know for sure is that it will be easier to use the indirect method. Therefore,$$1-P(\text{No students})-P(\text{No teachers})=1-\frac{\binom{10}{5}}{\binom{25}{5}}-\frac{\binom{15}{5}}{\binom{25}{5}} \dots$$I know that the no teachers covers for the probability of at least one teacher but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Complement of the event "at least one student AND at least two teachers" is "either there will be no student or there will be at most one teacher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ denote the event that there will be no student in the committee and $B$ denote the event that there will be at most $1$ teacher in the committee. Then the required event is $(A \cup B)^c.$

Let $C$ denote the event there will be no teacher in the committee and $D$ denote the event that there will be exactly one teacher in the committee. Then $B = C \cup D.$ Observe that $C$ and $D$ are mutually exclusive events. Hence $\Bbb P(B) = \Bbb P(C) + \Bbb P(D).$ So what is $\Bbb P(A \cap B)$?

> > $$\begin{align} \Bbb P(A \cup B) & = \Bbb P(A) + \Bbb P(B) - \Bbb P(A \cap B). \\ & = \Bbb P(A) + \Bbb P(C) + \Bbb P(D) - \Bbb P ((A \cap C) \cup (A \cap D)).\\ & = \Bbb P(A)+ \Bbb P(C) + \Bbb P(D) - \Bbb P(A \cap C) - \Bbb P(A \cap D). \end{align}$$

But $A \cap C$ and $A \cap D$ are impossible events. Can you see why? So $\Bbb P(A \cap C) = \Bbb P(A \cap D) = 0.$

Therefore

> > $$\begin{align} \Bbb P(A \cup B) & = \Bbb P(A) + \Bbb P(C) + \Bbb P (D). \\ & = \frac {\binom {10} {5}} {\binom {25} {5}} + \frac {\binom {15} {5}} {\binom {25} {5}} + \frac {\binom {15} {4} \cdot \binom {10} {1}} {\binom {25} {5}}. \\ & = \frac {7} {22}.\end{align}$$

So the probability of the required event $(A \cup B)^c$ is

> > $$\begin{align} \Bbb P((A \cup B)^c) & = 1 - \Bbb P(A \cup B).\\ & = 1 - \frac {7} {22}. \\ & = \frac {15} {22}. \end{align}$$

Comment: Is the new equation 1- P(no students) - P(at most 1 teacher) ? Also how would I calculate the at most 1 teacher part?

Comment: sorry if this a really dumb question but why is everything added? Shouldn't it be subtraction?

Comment: thank you so much! :)